# CiviCASE - edit / report on 'Detail'?

Tags: civicase

When creating a case, one of the fields is 'Detail'. It's a very useful description area for the case. However, can anyone point me to where it is then displayed or is editable? I can't find it on any reports or any screens. Could of course be an operator head-space error on my part.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the Open Case activity that gets created on the case. When you create a case it's the same as creating the Open Case activity.

Comment: Well that was simple. Thanks. It felt like a permament case description and attached to 'case' rather than 'activity'.  Now I can sort our process appropriately to take account of it.